# Accessing frame in IE: results from translate.google.com

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-translate, frames

I know there is an API from google, which does exactly this. But, there is always a but, ... I would like to access the normal translate service available for each normal user which has a screen, a browser and a keyboard. Let´s say this is more of academic interest. Also because I have the same problem in other applications.
OK, my program is very, but very simple.

```
 $objIE = New-Object -Com Internetexplorer.Application
 $url = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=it&tl=en&text=questo%20testo%20voglio%20tradurre"
 $objIE.Navigate($url)
```

Now I have the translation, in this case from italian to english. The translated text is in an element

```
 <span class="tlid-translation translation"><span title="" class="">I want to translate this text</span></span>
```

How do I arrive at this text ? 
It should be quite easy, since I have to navigate only in the DOM. But how ? I fail with the frames construct. I post this in spite of the API available, since my interest is more in the navigation inside the frame. With this we have an example available for everybody to test.

Thx a lot for every hint,

Comment: You can not access the iframe from another domain because of the same origin policy.

Comment: I do not understand, just as the browser can read the data, I should read it too, thru the API, or am I wrong ? I'm not using javascript, I am accessing the DOM from browser site

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am at the beginning of a solution. 
    $objIE.Document.body 
contains the desired translation. I can save this in a text and simply parse this text.
The desired translation is inside the following string
     <span class="tlid-translation" translation><span title="">Translated text</span>

Translated text is, as you may guess the translated text, this seems to work quite fine.
Very easy, but ...  also very fast.

Comment: From your last post. I can see that you had find the solution for your issue. I suggest you to mark it as an answer for this thread after 24 hrs may help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.